# concatenate two integers into a char * in C

Tags: c, char, int, concatenation, string-concatenation

Having forgotten my C knowledge now, having a really hard time figuring out how to do the following:

```
int a = 5; //getting value from a function
int b = 1; //from a function
```

what I want to have is:

```
char * returnstring = "5:1"; //want to return this
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
    char astr[5], bstr[5];
    sprintf( astr, "%d", a);
    sprintf( bstr, "%d", b);

    char finstr[100]; //final string
    strcpy(finstr, astr);
    strcpy(finstr, ":");
    strcpy(finstr, bstr);

    printf ("%s", finstr);
```

Comment: why downvoted? mind explaining? just a newbie asking a basic question in C here??

Comment: NMDV: `bstr[5]; sprintf( bstr, "%d", b);` is certainly susceptible to overruns.

Comment: As to why a DV, "but it doesn't work." is a DV magnet.  Instead explain what happened and what was expected.  As it stands, it looks like like a HW question without even an attempted compile and run.

Comment: `strcpy()` doesn't concatenate, it replaces. If you want to concatenate, you should be using `strcat()`.

Comment: `char *` is a pointer. Why (and how) do you want to concatenate two integers into a pointer??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just do it with one `sprintf`:

```
char str[100];
sprintf(str, "%d:%d", a, b);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
strcpy(finstr,astr);
strcpy(finstr, ":");
strcpy(finstr, bstr);
```

to

```
strcpy(finstr,astr);
strcat(finstr, ":");
strcat(finstr, bstr);
```

You are overwriting the result string with each successive call. You should instead concatenate to the end of the string, using `strcat`. Although this can just as easily be done with a single `sprintf` call.